# In blade, I want to print out all the items except $id item that is from model

Tags: php, laravel

In Controller,

```
  public function detail($id)
  {
      $item = Item::find($id);

      return view('frontend.detail',compact('item'));
  }
```

In blade,

```
{{$item->subcategory->items}} //question //this code print all the items//
```

Comment: Your question is not clear what are the value subcategory->items has and what you don't want to print out of that

Comment: {{$item->subcategory->items}} this code is print all the items .I want all the items except  $id from Model.like if item_id=11 that is from model but I want the all the item except item_id 11;.

Comment: You might receive better help if you show us the model of `Item` and `Subcategory` a sample dataset and what is displayed in the end. At this point it's not clear what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the items manually if you don't want to fetch the id
Currently, you are fetching all the items by using     $item = Item::find($id); it means that fetch all the fields of the particular table againt the given id.

you can use below query by modifying you required fields

```
Item::select('name','surname')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to make hidden id of the column in query Example

```
Item::find($id)->makeHidden(['id']);
return view('frontend.detail',compact('item'));
```